# How to remove md5 from the filename in the requested URL for the file name without md5 using apache mod_rewrite?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

Example:

This => URL request ./any_folder/main.d25a1b054a0b0fbeb3def5a0ff50d01e.min.js

For this => URL request ./any_folder/main.min.js

My htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Remove md5 from asset files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+).([a-fA-F0-9]{32}).(.+)?(js|css)$ $1.$3 [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

The above configuration does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have your htaccess rules file following manner. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    
# Remove md5 from asset files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
##RewriteRule ^([^.]*)\.(?:[[:alnum:]]{32})\.([^.]*)\.(js|css)/?$ $1.$2.$3 [L]
##Since following has worked for OP, so adding it here, commenting above.
RewriteRule ^(.+).([a-fA-F0-9]{32}).(.+)?(js|css)$ $1.$4 [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

# Send Requests To Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Hello Ravinder sorry for delay im very busy now. Im get you code test and make some changes in # Remove md5 from asset files part, my final version is this:
    # Remove md5 from asset files
    RewriteRule ^(.+).([a-fA-F0-9]{32}).(.+)?(js|css)$ $1.$4 [L] its working perfect here, very tks for help.

Comment: @BaDcereal, sure, whenever you get time you could edit my answer since I could see very minor changes in your and mine one, cheers and happy learning 